# windows 7 blue screen when only ram slot 2 is used

Tags: memory, bsod

I built a HTPC for my parents a week ago and the HTPC is throwing a blue screen. I get the following error messages.

1. pfn_list_corrupt
2. page fault in non paged area

i did a little bit of researching and concluded that this is ram related problem. I disassembled my HTPC then found out that the a single ram (4gb) was inserted into the ram slot #2. I switched it to slot 1 and....HTPC works fine now.

The problem is that it was working just fine with ram slot 2.

I have two questions.

1. Does it make a problem when I skip ram slot 1 then use 2 only?
2. If #1 makes problem, does changing the slot to #1 fixes the problem permanently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some boards require a special order when inserting RAM. Maybe your Board needs the first RAM to be insert into slot #1. Or the slot #2 is damaged and causes the issues. Try it with slot #1 and if this works fine, leave it this way and enjoy your HTPC.